# Jquery object selector as string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to get the selector for a jquery object

e.g in firefox I see a jquery object as [p.basket]

but there seems to be no way in jquery that I can get this selector?

Is there any way?

Phil

Comment: Possible duplicate of: **[How can i get selector from jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970)**

Answer (score 2):

If a jQuery object was created with a selector string, then you can just look at its "selector" property. However, not all jQuery objects are so constructed. Thus you should make sure to check for `null`.

*edit* — if your jQuery object was **not** constructed with a selector, then there simply is not a selector available. The library does not have any built-in way of *creating* a selector that matches the set of elements it contains. You could do that yourself, though it's not clear why it would be useful; once you have a reference to the DOM elements (which you do if the jQuery object isn't empty), isn't that more useful?

Comment: "not all jQuery objects are so constructed", can you elaborate that? Sounds very interesting, I do not know what queries do have this behaviour or not.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne well for example if you already have a reference to a DOM element, and you pass it to `jQuery()`, then you get a jQuery object wrapped around that element, and there is no selector.

Answer (score 1):

Is the [selector](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) property what you want?

Comment: nope, i found the selector property and that doesn't work as it was not constructed that way