# How to know the selector inside jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a plugin like

```
jQuery.fn.Foo = function () { 

    //var str=   get selector some_how; alert(str);      

    //at this point get selector that invoked this function

    //eg:
    /*
         jQuery('.red').Foo(); // alerts .red
         jQuery('#something_else') // alerts  #something_else
    */


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680498/jquery-object-selector-as-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery objects have a selector attribute.  You can access `this.selector`.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I get selector strings inside my plugins in 2017:

```js
(function($, window, document, undefined) { 
    $.fn._init = $.fn.init
    $.fn.init = function( selector, context, root ) {
        return (typeof selector === 'string') ? new $.fn._init(selector, context, root).data('selector', selector) : new $.fn._init( selector, context, root );
    };
    $.fn.getSelector = function() {
        return $(this).data('selector');
    };
    $.fn.coolPlugin = function() {
        var selector = $(this).getSelector(); 
        if(selector) console.log(selector); // outputs p #boldText
    }
})(jQuery, window, document);

// calling plugin
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p #boldText").coolPlugin();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>some <b id="boldText">bold text</b></p>
```

The idea is to conditionally wrap jQuery's `init()` function based on whether a selector string is provided or not. If it is provided, use jQuery's `data()` method to associate the selector string with the original `init()` which is called in the end. Small `getSelector()` plugin just takes previously stored value. It can be called later inside your plugin. It should work well with all jQuery versions.

Comment: may jquery version under 3.0 there is no need to use this trick but, above 3.0 very useful. Thanks.