# setTimout screws up variable javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, settimeout

I'm having trouble with a piece of script that removes an object X amount of time after it has gotten the class 'hidden'

```
selector = getselector($(this).parent().parent());
console.log("Clicked Cancel");
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('hidden');
setTimeout(function() {
    $(selector).remove();
}, 400);
```

I edited some piece of script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2421383/1417953) to make function *getselector* since $(this) doesn't work within a setTimeout.
now this piece of code works, as long as you don't run it too quickly again.
problem seems to be that variable *selector* gets messed up when a another node gets deleted within the timespan (currently 400ms)

and I can't think of an easy way around it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: Don't make `selector` global, i.e. use `var`. Oh, and simply store the element instead of trying to build a selector:

```
var elem = $(this).parent().parent();
elem.addClass('hidden');
setTimeout(function() {
    elem.remove();
}, 400);
```

Comment: why couldn't I think of that... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also queue the removal in the following way, which makes your Code a little bit more spicy:

```
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('hidden').delay(400).queue(function() {
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a variable with a value true at the start of the process. On action, check whether it is not false and then set it to false and then back to true once finished. If you click it too fast, it will check your variable, see it is true again and will do the action again.