# Why does the .selector property in jQuery not store a valid selector value?

Tags: jquery

Assuming I have HTML similar to this:

```
<div class="fooContainer">
    <div class="barContainer">
        <a href="#">foo-bar</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If in script my entry point is the anchor and I need to get to the div with the class fooContainer I can do this:

```
var $fooContainer = $("a").parents(".fooContainer");
```

This works perfectly fine as `$fooContainer` now holds the reference to the element in the DOM.

When I now print out the `selector` value like this:

```
console.log($fooContainer.selector)
```

I get the value `a.parents(.fooContainer)`.

I was under the impression that the `selector` property returned a string which itself would be a valid selector value.

This is not the case though as when trying to use it as a selector like this:

```
$("a.parents(.fooContainer)")
```

It cannot find a match in jQuery 1.7.2.
And in the latest jQuery 1.8.x it even throws an exception: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a.parents(.fooContainer)`

- Why does the selector property not contain a valid selector value?
- If it doesn't what would one use the `selector` property for?

I tried searching the jQuery [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com) for information but was not able to find anything related to that property.

Comment: This is a private (as in "not documented in the API") property. You understand you're asking us to explain the internal implementation of a library ?

Comment: The reason you can't find `.selector` in the API documentation is probably because it was intended for internal use only. You wouldn't be expected to use it at all, and you won't find it documented anywhere official.

Comment: @dystroy: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't aware of `.selector` being private. If it was only intended for internal use I more than happily stay away from it :) No need to explain internal implementations to me. I would have loved to see any documentation on it though. where do I find that information?

Comment: I don't think using .selector for your own logic is supported, but here is another question where .selector discussed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object

Comment: You might also want to read more about Sizzle (selector engine used by jQuery) if you're curious: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/07/04/the-new-sizzle/

Comment: Thank you for all the info and links. +1 to that. I'm glad I found out about it now rather than later after missusing the API all over the place.

Comment: Not sure why votes are being casted to close this question as `off-topic`. I used the `$("#elementid").selector` property in my application, it did not do what I expected it to do. I asked why it is and luckily I got an answer before the question is closed which solved my software development and programming issue. I re-phrased my question in the post. Should be quite clear now that the issue was programming related.

Comment: I initially voted to close because API implementation is generally considered as not debatable on SO (should be debated with the owners of the code). Then I thought again that this was an accessible property and that jQuery isn't just the small component of a closed company but both one of the most used library and a very small (thus studyable) open source code. This is why I answered. I couldn't remove my close vote but I can now vote to reopen. The line between private implementation we can't discuss and this case is thin, thus the risk to have such problem.

Comment: @dystroy: Thanks for explaining this as I was a little surprised about the closing votes. I checked the FAQ as well and wasn't able to see how this question was not programming related. The way you explained it though I can at least see now why that was the case. I tried re-phrasing my question a little to make it more applicable. Regardless I'm glad you answered it and hopefully anyone else miss-using `.selector` will find this question useful. Thanks again for the reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily read [the source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) but what isn't documented [in the browsable API](http://api.jquery.com/) is internal and private.

By definition.

So this is an implementation detail, and a property you really shouldn't try to use as there is no guarantee, neither for the future versions nor for any use you might imagine today.

Comment: That is very interesting. Thank you for all the usefull information. I wasn't aware of the `if it is not documented it is internal or private.` I agree 100% on your last statement. It is to risky alright. I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss the documentation. I didn't use `.selector` before but when I noticed it today I thought it was something I can use. Which is clear now, no it is not :) I will remember what you said about the documentation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: They now have a section called *internals*, which I think means private APIs. Here's the [sparse] documentation on [`.selector`](http://api.jquery.com/selector/).