# js, How to get selector from element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am no sure whether I made the question title right, but I want to ask a question below

```
<div title="A"></div>

var a = $([title=A]);

//if I only know a, how can I get what is referring here made a, 
//or command I use can get out put of the referring. 
//This case the out put will be '[title=A]'
```

I am not asking for `a.attr('title');`

Comment: I think you need to re-word this question.

Comment: Your wording is very confusing. Do you mean that you want the selector that was used to retrieve the value that was assigned by jquery to `a`?

Comment: Thank you, do you mean the question title does not match the actual question?

Comment: yes, I think I want to know the selector...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `selector` property in jQuery object to get the selector that was used.

```
var a = $('[title=A]');
alert(a.selector);  //will alert [title=A]
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Zz4MW/

**Note:** Use `selector` property with caution as it is for internal usage. See [Why does the .selector property in jQuery not store a valid selector value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426622/why-does-the-selector-property-in-jquery-not-store-a-valid-selector-value) for more information.

Comment: That is not reliable--see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426622/why-does-the-selector-property-in-jquery-not-store-a-valid-selector-value).

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $('[title=A]');
console.log(a.get()[0]);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Zz4MW/1/)**

See http://api.jquery.com/get/ for more info on .get()

Comment: `a.get()[0]` == `a.get(0)` == `a[0]`.