# Get Selector from a JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

For Example, this will give me:

```
 console.log($(".smartgridview-normal").selector)
 //result is  '.smartgridview-normal'.
```

[image]

My code is :

```
    $( '.smartgridview-normal th' ).live( 'dblclick', function () {
        var optimalWidth = parseFloat( $( this ).attr( 'data-width' ) );
        console.log( $(this).selector );// At this point I need the selector
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    } );
```

My Log is giving me an empty string. There is no selector for 'this' object. Is there any way to get the selector of the element which 'this' is pointing to?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you try first before posting the question?

Comment: I tried. I could't get it working.

Comment: I'm getting an empty string

Comment: Your screenshot is very small. can you post a bigger screenshot or copy the code and paste it?

Comment: Which selector you are looking for with `$(this)`? The one that was used to attach the handler?

Comment: What is the desired value of `var selector`?

Comment: I'm looking for the selector of the current element that caused the event. In my case 'this' will point to the current element.

Comment: @AkhilSekharan _which_ selector? The one that was used to attach the handler? Any selector that selects only that element?

Comment: If an element has an ID, then `'#'+this.id` is one possible selector for that element.

Comment: I don't think there is any such thing as "selector of the current element". You only know that your current element matches the initial selector. Except of course if your current element has an id (or you give it an id).

Comment: Better question is - why do you need the selector? Beware the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: To give you an analogy of what you're asking: Say there's a guy called John Smith. His kids call him Dad, or Daddy. His wife, darling, sweetie or John. His mother, my Johnny, or sometimes John Tiberius Smith. When you call him, you know what you called him. But when you meet him in the city waiting to meet someone, you have no idea what name was used to summon him there. All you know is, he's John Smith. `this` is John Smith himself; `$('.foo th')` is the phone conversation that brought him to that intersection.

Comment: @Amadan. I got it. Thanks. So in short there is no jquery selector for this pointer. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object: it's an older question, maybe "the historical one" about this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I see where your problem is. `$(this)` is not constructed using a selector, but rather by directly wrapping a DOM element, so it does not carry it anywhere. You can get the original selector obviously by doing `$('.smartgridview-normal th').selector`; but there's a big difference between `$('.smartgridview-normal th')` and `$(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

As Amadan said, inside the click handler `this` refers to the element, not the jQuery object

It's not perfect, but you could cache the jQuery object

```
var elements = $("#mySelector")
$elements.on("dblclick", function(event){
    console.log($elements.selector);
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4uey/2/) for testing

Comment: What's the point of `$(elements)` when `elements` is already a jQuery object?

Comment: @JanDvorak Visual consistency. Similar to the consistency of your pedantry :-P

Comment: You could name the variable `$elements`. I think it's cleaner than rewrapping it unneccessarily.

Comment: @JanDvorak You are absolutely correct. It was just force of habit. Is there a signicant reason to prefix the variable with a `$`? Or is it purely cosmetic?

Comment: @Enrico: good habit to distinguish wrapped elements from unwrapped. No formal reasons, but increases readability and maintainability. (Now if only I could remember to do it consistently :D )

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, `"#"+this.id` is the best you can hope for if the element has an id. If not, the only information you have is that the element belongs to your original selection `'.smartgridview-normal th'`.

You could always add the id yourself within the code (for example unique id based on the current date and time).

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Perl/PHP :) We don't hold with dot concatenation here :D

Answer (score -2):

Try using `nodeName` instead of `selector`,

```
var selector = $(this)[0].nodeName;
```

Or,

```
var selector = this.nodeName;
```

Comment: Do you realise `$(this)[0] === this`?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps set it to a variable first?

```
var sel = "answer";
$("#"+sel).on("dblclick", function(event){
   console.log("Current selector is "+sel);
});​
```