# jQuery: use .on() instead of .live() to attach event handler to $('selector') object

Tags: jquery, jquery-on, jquery-1.9

I understand that .live() has been removed from jQuery 1.9 and that .on() should be used instead. So far .on() has worked perfectly for me if the selector is a string. For example,

```
$("a.offsite").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });
```

turned into

```
$(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });
```

But how do I use .on() for a JQuery selector object (or a collection of objects) as follows?

```
var jele = $('.nav').find("a.offsite");
$(jele).live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });
```

turned into

```
var jele = $('.nav').find("a.offsite");
$(document).on("click", jele, function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });
```

Is the code above converted correctly? The problem I encounter is other event handlers bound to the same event yet different selector are also executed when the event fires. Hence I suspect this is not the correct way but I can't find any similar example in the official documentation.

I know I could have passed the selector string instead of the jele object into .on() method but in some cases I simply do not have access to the selector string, eg. when the jele object is passed as an argument into the function in which the binding occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the JQuery `jele` object, try to call the `.on()` function on `jele`:

```
$(jele).on("click", your-code-here);
```

Other way to do it is having the selector string of `jele`. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object) I found about retrieving the selector string of any JQuery object. Once you have the `jele` selector string, your code should be as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", selector, your-code-here);
```

Comment: Thanks but this will not work if jele's html element has not existed yet (eg. loaded using AJAX). That's the reason why I used .live() initially. To quote the documentation, "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."

Comment: Okay, I understand you now. Let me edit my answer and I hope I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(jele).on("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });
```

Comment: Thanks but see my reply to JordiVilaplana's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`.on()` replace `.bind()`, `.live()` and `.delegate()`

usage:

```
$('div').on('click',function(){/* ... */}); //equivalent to .bind()
```

this 3 lines are equivalent:

```
$('a','#menu').live('click',function(){/* ... */});
$('#menu').delegate('a','click',function(){/* ... */}); 
$('#menu').on('click','a',function(){/* ... */});
```