# How to save instance of object (and options) to apply methods in future

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write an extension to jQuery, whereby you can pass methods by strings, and apply these methods to the element specified. However, I cannot understand how calling a method this way can determine the options that were originally set when the method was called.

Consider this (using jQuery UI as example):

```
$('#foo').datepicker({ someoption: true });

$('#foo').datepicker('setDate','10/10/2013');
```

How does the second call know what `someoption` is set too?

If, for instance, the `someoption` was `dateFormat` then the datepicker would automatically change the format of the supplied date to match the format specified in `formatDate`... How does the second call know what the value of `formatDate` is?

The only way I can see how this is achieved is like so (obviously missing a few details):

```
var datepickers = new Array();

$.fn.datepicker = datepicker;
function datepicker(options){
    // Get the selector somehow
    var selector = somefunction($(this));
    // Save the options to the datepickers array
    // for the given selector
    datepickers[selector] = options;
}
```

Is this the correct way to go about achieving this? If so, how does one get the selector and is it reliable (potential solution to this part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object))?

Comment: Have you had a look at the source of the plugin?

Comment: @FelixKling Theres a thought!! hahaha, can't believe I didnt think of that! I only used the `datepicker` as an example but I guess the solution would lie in there! Either way, if anybody does have any opinions or potential solutions, I would still be keen to see :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only way I can see how this is achieved is like so

Yeah, storing them in a static variable in the plugin's scope is one way. However: You need a reliable way to determine a unique `selector` for all DOM elements (your `somefunction`), and you will run into memory leaks since you do not know when you can un-store the information.

Instead, most plugins do use the standard [jQuery `.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/), which will take care of both issues. From the [datepicker source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js):

```
// in the init function:
$.data(target, "datepicker", inst);

// in other methods:
var inst = $.data(target, "datepicker");
```

Other ways (just for completeness): Store the data directly on properties of the DOM object (which can cause memory leaks on certain known browsers), or returning a widget instance object from the method (instead of the chainable jQuery wrapper - which requires a different invocation strategy than the one you requested).

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thank you! Could you possibly post an example of this?

Comment: Would it be something like this: `$(this).data('datepicker',options);`?

Comment: @BenCarey Take a look at [jQuery UI's Widget](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js), the base class for all UI components in the library. The [`$.widget.bridge`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L165) method takes care of creating a method on `$.fn` which either creates a widget instance or calls a method of the current instance.

Comment: @BenCarey Yes, that's also how jQuery UI does it. For reading it uses [`$.data(this, name)`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L202) and for writing it uses [`$.data(this, name, new object(...))`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L206) (where `object` is the widget's constructor).

Comment: @BenCarey: Yes, exactly. Though most plugins do use the "internal" [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function directly.