# Generate selector for same attributes element from click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

What I'm trying to do here is this:

```
function newFunction( element ){
    var newSelector = element.getSelector();
}

$('.class li a').on('click', function(){
    newFunction( $(this) );
})
```

There is no getSelector function, so how can I do this?

I thought about getting first the html tag of `$(this)` and then its parent and so on but I cannot find a way to get the html tag (not content) of `$(this)`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What are your trying to do?

Comment: Am I? And how to I get it into a variable? `$(this)` is the whole element, no the selector.

Comment: I guess you want to get `'.class li a'`, Might help [How can i get selector from jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object)

Comment: @Satpal yes, that's what I want, but I want to run the function no matter what I'm clicking on, so I want `.class li a` and `.otherClass li` and `whateverElement div ul li`, do I explain myself?

Answer (score 0):

You just want the selector property - there's no getter function...

```
function newFunction(element) {
    var newSelector = $(element).selector;
}

$('.class li a').on('click', function(){
    newFunction(this);
})
```

(I passed the html element into the function, but you can obviously do it the way you originally have it.  I just have OCD about that :p )

Comment: selector is deprecated since 1.7, I rather don't use it.

Comment: Ah - okay.  I wasn't aware of either that fact or that you want to use a later version.  Can you specify the version you're using in the question if it's important?

Answer (score -1):

Just use the jQuery method `prop()`:

```
function newFunction( element ){
    var newSelector = element.prop("tagName");
}
```

**NOTE:** This will return the element's tag name capitalized (e.g. for an `img` element, `prop("tagName")` will return `IMG`).

Comment: Please do not say "but I cannot find a way to get the html tag (not content) of $(this)" if you do not want to know how to do that. This solution is for that problem.

Comment: I do want to know that, I didn't downvoted your answer, I guess who did it thought that it is not a "complete" answer or something.

Comment: Ok, try Satpal's link. Might be what you're looking for.