# Get the css selector of the element, my plugin is applied on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a jQuery Plugin which gets applied on a container element like that.

```js
$('#container').myPlugin();
```

In this plugin I am trying to get the same element from another page trough `.get()`.

```js
$.get('page.php', function(data) {
    data = $.parseHTML(data);
    data = $('<div/>').html(data);

    data = data.find( myContainer );

}, 'html');
```

The problem is the `myContainer`-variable. I need the CSS-selector, which was applied to my plugin, is there any way I can get it?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object) solution, but it seems fairly complex. Maybe there is an easier solution especially for my case (plugin not object)?!

I could use another option in my plugin to get the selector, but I would like to avoid it, since it would feel like doubled information for the user. (Applying the plugin to the container and reference it in options).

Answer (score 0):

I would use `data-*` attribute:

```
<a href="/resource" data-target="#element"></a>
```

Then you can read the value easily in your plugin context using jQuery `.data('target')` method. Using selector is not a flexible solution, there are many cases that the logic will fail. Adding an useful/important attribute to the element doesn't make the markup *dirty*.

Comment: I think, I don’t quite understand it. If I would add a `data`-attribute to my container, this would require another action from the user and I can’t add it from inside the plugin, since I would need to know the selector, used for the element, my Plugin has been applied on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a solution:

```
var mySelector = $(this).selector
```

seems to work.

---

**Important**
`.selector` has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: Note that `selector` property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: Hm I am using it in jQuery 1.11.0 and it seems to work. Has it been deprecated without any replacement?