# How do I alert whatever is entered between the single quotes in the jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

```
<a href="#" class="myclass anotherclass" id="myid anotherid">Link</a>

$('.myclass').click(function () {
    var foo = '';
    alert(foo);
});
```

In this example, I want an alert to pop up as that says: ".myclass".

How do I alert whatever is entered between the single quotes in the jQuery selector?

EDIT: I want to ONLY alert "myclass". Not "myclass anotherclass"

Comment: `alert($(this).class);` ?

Comment: Are you using alert for debugging?

Comment: should probably use console.debug, console.log, .warn, .info, alerts to me just seem to get in the way...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object

Comment: @JustinE thank you, i will use console commands from now on. it's a bad habit.

Comment: Just FYI, your `id` on that anchor is invalid. Elements can only have one `id`, which cannot contain spaces and must be unique within a document. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id)

Answer (score 2):

When the click event happens, the jQuery object that was used to bind it no longer exists. Neither the element nor the event handler have any information about the jQuery object that was used. If you want information from the jQuery object, you have to keep it:

```
var c = $('.myclass');
c.click(function () {
  alert(c.selector);
});
```

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 1):

For the delegated handlers you can get the selector property of `handleObj` property of the event object:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function (e) {
    console.log(e.handleObj.selector); // => .myclass
});
```

But note, that for direct attached handlers the selector will be `null` and you need to use @Guffa's [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184476/259946)

```
$('.myclass').click(function(e) {
    console.log(e.handleObj.selector); // => null  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
alert($(this).attr('class'));
```

Comment: i forgot my attr...whoops...I don't code in jquery very often as you can atell...

Comment: Yes, but that returns "myclass anotherclass". I want to just return "myclass".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to get the selector to the object which ever you used for bind the click event. For usual cases `$object.selector` do your trick but it would not work in even `$(this).selector` so as a workaround you can send the parameter like below;

```
var a = $('.myclass')
a.click({sel : a.selector}, function () {
    alert(this.sel);
});
alert($('.myclass').selector)
```