# Turning a jQuery element into a string you can use inside a selector

Tags: jquery

Let's say you have the following div:

```
<div id="someId">
</div>
```

You get the div by using:

```
var element = $('#someId');
```

How can you turn element into '#someId'? I would also like an answer that work for more complex cases where there are multiple classes and ids.

I want to do this, because I would like to append that string into another selector to target very specific DOM elements.

Comment: You mean [get the selector from a jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object)? Are you sure you need it? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It's useful when repeating divs all have the same class names.

Comment: You can use [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to search the descendants. It even has a `.find($element)` override. I don't understand the use case that requires it.

Comment: I want to do the opposite.