# How to get a selector from a function?

Tags: jquery

I need to pass a special selector to an event handler. The special selector is calculated by a function:

```
var getSelectableItems = function () {
    return $('.item').not('.disabled');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $body = $('body');
    $body.on('click', $(getSelectableItems()), function () {
        // .. do something
    });
});
```

The `getSelectableItems()` method is just a sample. My real code looks different. My point is: how can I have a function return a selector and use this selector in the kind of click event handler shown?

My current solution fires on every click / any DOM element. But I want the click event to fire only on clicks on DOM elements returned by a function.

Comment: This seems like an XY question. Can you give details of what you're actually trying to achieve, as I'm sure there are much better ways than what you are attempting to do.

Comment: You need to return a selector, not a jQuery object... so `return '.item:not(.disabled)';`

Comment: If I understand you correctly you could select desired items via in eq. $('item').not('disabled') and then use this [function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object) to create selector for that elements.

Comment: Ohhhhh. The 2nd parameter needs to be a string. Arun's solution is what I was looking for. So simple ;) Thanks everbody!!

Answer (score 1):

See if this works,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dumbVar = $('body');
    dumbVar.on('click', $(getSelectableItems()), function () {
        // .. do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work; the second parameter of `on()` has to be a string. see http://api.jquery.com/on for more details. Logically this is no different to what the OP currently has.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But it worked when I done it accidentally in a project of mine

Answer (score 0):

You can create click handler on needed selector(elements that have class *.item* and don't have class *.disabled*):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $body = $('body');
    $body.on('click', '.item:not(.disabled)', function () {
        // .. do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, Anna, this works in the sample. But I really need a function because my real scenario is a little more complex. Anyways: I already have a working solution based on Arun's answer (see above). Thanks so much for your effort though!