# Is there a better way to get a selector string out of a JavaScript event.target object?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

While looking through JavaScript the event.target object, I can see all the typical parameters of the node- things like the nodeName, ID, and classes. However, I want to convert it to a string like `h1.entry-title` for example.

I can see Chrome DevTools does this:

In the inspector:

[image: devtools inspector]

and in the console:

[image: devtools console]

Since I can't find the overall "selector" as a string, I figured I would need to do it myself. Here's what I came up with:

```js
//Convert DOM objects into selector strings (tag#id.class)
function domObjectToSelector(object){
    //If a jQuery object was passed, use the proper node
    if ( !object.nodeType ){
        object = object[0];
    }

    var selector = object.nodeName.toLowerCase();

    if ( object.id ){
        selector += '#' + object.id;
    }

    if ( object.className ){
        selector += '.' + object.className.replace(/\s/g, '.');
    }

    return selector;
}
```

**Is there a better way to do this, or does this seem like the right approach?** It just feels like I'm over-engineering this...

Comment: Don't know the goal of this, but the returned selector isn't unique to that element if there is no `id` attribute. That makes the function name a bit misleading or ambiguous.

Comment: Good point. In this use case non-unique selectors won't be a problem, but I will keep that in mind to improve the function name, thanks.

Comment: What _is_ the use case? You already have a reference to the Object. Why the need for a selector?

Comment: If xpath works for you , there is this answer that returns xpath - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631931/301303

Comment: This is for detecting and logging possible UX issues. This part of the functionality is simply showing a *general* guide of what the problematic element was.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420970/how-can-i-get-selector-from-jquery-object/15623322#15623322

Comment: Thanks @Kravimir that is a great reference.